# How to fix trace trap / SIGTRAP when running google-chrome in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, chrome, selenium

having an issue running that's driving me crazy and would love to have some help debugging. Basically, I'm trying to install Google Chrome on Debian stretch for use with selenium and, while the install goes fine, it crashes on boot with a SIGTRAP

I have tried installing about 10 different versions of Chrome and I get the same output:

`google-chrome --version`

> trace trap  google-chrome

If I run with `strace` I get the following output (truncated showing the last few lines)

> mprotect(0x7f91db20e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
> mprotect(0x7f91dbaca000, 28672, PROT_READ) = 0
> mprotect(0x7f91dbe13000, 20480, PROT_READ) = 0
> mprotect(0x7f91db8a0000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
> mprotect(0x560e58168000, 8253440, PROT_READ) = 0
> mprotect(0x7f91dc9c7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
> munmap(0x7f91dc9ba000, 51848)           = 0
> set_tid_address(0x7f91dc90bed0)         = 12969
> set_robust_list(0x7f91dc90bee0, 24)     = 0
> rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f91dc388bd0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f91dc3940e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
> rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f91dc388c60, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f91dc3940e0}, NULL, 8) = 0
> rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
> getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
> getrandom("\31\366\336bs\314C\251", 8, 0) = 8
> getrandom("\340\364w\342"\321\363\304", 8, 0) = 8
> mmap(0xb8400000000, 8589934592, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
> mmap(0xb8400000000, 8589934592, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
> --- SIGTRAP {si_signo=SIGTRAP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
> +++ killed by SIGTRAP +++

Thank you!!